# Is there a way to overwrite bigQuery table based on partition and cluster columns from Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have parquet data partitioned like:

```
batch_date=2023-03-03/batch_hour=08
```

I have to copy this data in BigQuery table. The table I created have **batch_data** as partitioned column and **batch_hour** as clustering column.

I am not to overwrite the data properly in BigQuery table as the requirement is to overwrite the data for a **batch_date** and a **batch_hour**.

To write the data from Spark, I have given:

```
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).format("bigquery")
.option("partitionField", "batch_date")
.option("clusterFields", "batch_hour")
.option("datePartition", "batch_date")
.option("temporaryGcsBucket", "temp_bucket")
//All other table options
.save()
```

By the above code, only the batch_date which is provided gets overwritten but it overwrites all the **batch_hour** for a **batch_date**.

Let me know, is there a way to overwrite only an **hour** for a **date**.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes the Spark BigQuery connector supports a single partition overwrite at the moment, which means that in your case the data in the entire partition (i.e. for a given date) is deleted.

However, depends on the amount of days you need the data you can partition it on an hourly basis. In this case, each partition represents a single hour (not day) so an overwrite will erase just this specific hour. Notice that the limit of 4000 partitions per table still hold, so assuming you have records for all 24 hours, this gives you roughly 165 days of data.